# How to grab text from a button using onclick in an async callback to generate map for leafletjs?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet to generate a map. Whenever I click on a button I want to color the map base on an attribute. I'm trying to use the **this** keyword to grab the inner text of button. And use the return of the text inside of an async/await call. I've tried referring to this [Plain English javascript blog post](https://plainenglish.io/blog/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-clicked-element-in-the-javascript-click-handler-8ca398d848d6) on how to use the this keyword. But I'm hitting a dead in. I can print out the inner text in the console.log but I cannot actually save a reference to the text.

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Plain Leaflet API</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
crossorigin=""/>

 <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
     crossorigin=""></script>

<link href='./css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' />

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="options">
        <button id="vanilla" onclick="getButtonText()">Vanilla</button>
        <button id="strawberry"onclick="getButtonText()">Strawberry</button>
        <button id="chocolate"onclick="getButtonText()">chocolate</button>


    </div>

    <div id='map'></div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

Javascript

```
let map = L.map('map')
           .setView([41.83,-87.68],11)

let mapboxTiles = L.tileLayer(`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v12/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=${MAPBOX_API_TOKEN}`, {
       attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/feedback/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
       tileSize: 512,
       zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);

function getButtonText(){
       //console.log(this.id,this.innerHTML)
       return this.innerHTML;
}

let data_path = "data.geojson"



async function loadGeoJson(){
       let hexColor = null

     
       //read in the geojson data
       const response = await fetch(data_path)
       const data = await response.json()
      //console.log(data.features[0].properties)

    
       
     

       let addGeoJSON = L.geoJson(data, {
              
              style:function(feature){
                    
              let vanilla = document.getElementById('vanilla').onclick = getButtonText;
              let strawberry = document.getElementById('strawberry').onclick = getButtonText;
              let chocolate = document.getElementById('chocolate').onclick = getButtonText;
              console.log(vanilla)
                     
                    
              }
                     
          
              

       }).addTo(map)

}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have 2 functions with the same name `getButtonText`

Comment: Its a typo. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Why not rather control button names from Javascript. Then you don't have to get button name from HTML, instead you define names in your script and then insert them as button names in HTML from the script. That way you can do colorMap(btnId) function to any button where btnId is index of that button's name from array of names.

Comment: Hi, I think it's better to post some code when answering; this helps others  to reproduce what you suggest

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is the use of "onclick" handlers in HTML, which is not generally recommended outside of legacy use.

Did you know the HTML parser generates an  event handler function for you, from `oneventname` attrribute text content, of the form

```
 function(event) {
     // function body same as attribute text
 }
```

This means that "onclick = getButtonText" generates a handler that evaluates `getButtonText` as an object expression without even calling it.

If you must use HTML to add the event handler you could try attribute text like

```
onclick = "getButtonText(this);" // pass the handler's this value (the button), or

onclick = "getButtonText(event);" // pass the event object, or

onclick = "getButtonText.call(this, event);" // call with button as this
            and event as argument
```

In most cases passing either the `event` or `this` values will suffice.

Preferably add the button event handlers in script using `addEventListener` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I used the advice that both traktor and chutfica has given

```
let map = L.map('map')
           .setView([41.83,-87.68],11)

let mapboxTiles = L.tileLayer(`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v12/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=${MAPBOX_API_TOKEN}`, {
       attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/feedback/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
       tileSize: 512,
       zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);

let data_path = "data.geojson"


//div that contains buttons
let options = document.getElementById("options")

//create button element for each flavor

let vanilla = document.createElement('button')
vanilla.innerHTML = "Vanilla"

let chocolate = document.createElement('button')
chocolate.innerHTML = "Chocolate"

let strawberry = document.createElement('button')
strawberry.innerHTML = "Strawberry"

//add each button to the options div

options.appendChild(vanilla)
options.appendChild(chocolate)
options.appendChild(strawberry)


//add an event listener to each button
vanilla.addEventListener ("click", function() {
  let name = this.textContent.toUpperCase()
  loadGeoJson(name)
 });

chocolate.addEventListener ("click", function() {
       let name = this.textContent.toUpperCase()
       loadGeoJson(name)
      });

strawberry.addEventListener ("click", function() {
       let name = this.textContent.toUpperCase()
       loadGeoJson(name)
      });



async function loadGeoJson(name){
     
       //read in the geojson data
       const response = await fetch(data_path)
       const data = await response.json()
       console.log(data)
       //console.log(data.features[0].properties)


       let addGeoJSON = L.geoJson(data, {

              oneEachFeature: function(feature,layer){

              },
              
              style:function(feature){
                     let hexColor = null;
                      //console.log(name)

                     if(name == undefined){
                            hexColor = 'red'

                     }
                     else{
                            hexColor = feature.properties[name].hex
                     }
                     console.log(hexColor)
                     return{
                            fillColor:hexColor
                     }
             
                     
                    
              }
                     
          
              

       }).addTo(map)

}

loadGeoJson()
```